# How to load 4 integer values efficiently in neon register on msvc compiler?

Tags: visual-c++, neon

How do I implement below operation efficiently on msvc compiler?

```
uint32x4_t temp = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

I have to load 4 different values in neon register very efficiently since I am working to optimize performance. Above statement works for android clang but fails on msvc compiler since uint32x4_t is typedef'ed to __n128.

Following is the structure of __n128:

```
typedef union __declspec(intrin_type) _ADVSIMD_ALIGN(8) __n128
{
     unsigned __int64   n128_u64[2];
     unsigned __int32   n128_u32[4];
     unsigned __int16   n128_u16[8];
     unsigned __int8    n128_u8[16];
     __int64            n128_i64[2];
     __int32            n128_i32[4];
     __int16            n128_i16[8];
     __int8             n128_i8[16];
     float              n128_f32[4];

    struct
    {
        __n64  low64;
        __n64  high64;
    } DUMMYNEONSTRUCT;

} __n128;
```

Comment: Defining a 128-bit constant is not going to get it into NEON registers faster than just explicitly loading it (temp = vld1q_u32(...)).

Answer (score 0):

In C99, when initializing a union with a initializer list, you can specify the particular members that are initialized, as follows:

```
uint32x4_t temp = { .n128_u32 = {1,2,3,4} };
```

However, this C99 syntax is only supported in Visual Studio 2013 and higher. Visual Studio 2012 and below do not support this feature, and thus, you can only initialize a union with a static initializer based on the first entry (`n128_u64`). You could come up with an initializer that fits your uint32 data into uint64. Since they are constants, it will not take any additional execution time. Looks really ugly:

```
uint32x4_t temp = { { 1 << 32 | 2, 3 << 32, 4 } };
```

If this code needs to be portable between compilers, a better option would be to create a preprocessor macro, that handles formatting of constants.